# An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request (ASP.NETCore MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, internal-server-error

I'm working on an ASP NETCore MVC application and all work well when suddently I was stuck on a massive error, not on compiling but when I try to go to the website :

```
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Generated Code

One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.


The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
    4.[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Debug/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Debug_Index_cshtml))]

Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
    4.[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Debug/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Debug_Index_cshtml))]

Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
    4.[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Debug/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Debug_Index_cshtml))]

Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
    4.[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Debug/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Debug_Index_cshtml))]

The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    8.    using System;

The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    9.    using System.Collections.Generic;

The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    10.    using System.Linq;

The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    11.    using System.Threading.Tasks;

The type or namespace name 'ViewFeatures' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    14.    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
    40.    public class _Views_Debug_Index_cshtml : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<dynamic>
```

And this is just a small part on the error displayed on the browser.
Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: At a guess it sounds like some required DLLs were not included in the deployment

Comment: But it work well yesterday and I didn't change configuration or anything like that. I've just made an update for VS, can it be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new project and move all files into it, and it work, maybe not the best solution but well, it worked.